# addMethod() of jQuery validation plugin display error from title attribute

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

My Form code

```
<html:form styleId="myForm" action="/doAction" method="post">
    <html:text title="Transaction Name" styleId="transactionName" property="trans_name" />
    <input title="Upload" id="submit"  type="submit" name="submit" value='Upload' />
</html:form>
```

My addMethod() code

```
$.validator.addMethod("transcationRegex", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z0-9\-' ']+$/i.test(value);
}, "Must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes.");
```

Now when validation fail I don't get the message define in addMethod (i.e. "Must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes.") intsead it give message inside title of that field (i.e. "Transaction Name")

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: HTML is OK no wrong with display.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by

1. Removing error message from the addMethod() itself.
2. Putting the message as

   $("myForm").validate({
      rules: {
         trans_name: {
            transactionRegex:true
          }
      },
      messsage: {
           trans_name: {
            transactionRegex:"Must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes."
            //Note: Error message must be in double quote.
          }
      }
     });