# jQuery validation plugin using title instead of the error message specified

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, title, validation, customvalidator

When I attempt to create a method to use the methods provided in the additional-methods.js file I get the intended validation. However, if the user inputs a wrong value, instead of displaying the exception defined in the `additional-methods.js` file, the user sees the title of the current element, which is currently being used for type-hinting.

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
  //setup input validation
                validator = form.validate({
                    rules: {
                        city: {
                            required: true,
                            lettersonly: true
                        }
                    }
                }); 

  $('input, textarea').blur(function(){
                    element = $(this);

                    // if the user gave no value then show the this field is required
                    if(element.val() == element.attr('title')){ 
                        refreshError(element, 'This field is required');
                    }else if(element.val() == '') {  //if the value is empty then check if it was required, also check if it had an input hint
                        //if the element is required display the error message
                        if(element.hasClass('required')){ 
                            refreshError(element, 'This field is required');
                        }

                        //if the title exists then we assume it is the input hint
                        if(element.attr('title') != ''){
                            element.val(element.attr('title'));
                            element.addClass('inputHint');
                        }
                    }else{
                        //if we got input validate it
                        response = element.valid();
                        //if we got an error clear the old one(conditional on existance), and display the new one. Otherwise clear any old error
                        if(!response){
                            this.defaultShowErrors();
                        }else{
                            errorId = element.attr('id')+'Error';
                            $('#'+errorId).remove();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

With the relevant part of the form being:

```
<label for="city">City:</label>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="required inputHint" title="Your city here" />
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? I am using the 1.9.0 version of the [jQuery Validator plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

NB: I thought I had hit the nail on the head after reading: [addMethod() of jQuery validation plugin display error from title attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108761/addmethod-of-jquery-validation-plugin-display-error-from-title-attribute) but after trying:

```
                    //setup input validation
                validator = form.validate({
                    rules: {
                        city: {
                            required: true,
                            lettersonly: true
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        city: {
                            lettersonly: "you must give a valid city"
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I found that nothing changed.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information, like the contents of the additional-methods.js file.  My suggestion is to use `console.info` JavaScript statements to log/trace the behavior to see why the title is being used instead.

Comment: cool, I was doing that while pulling out my hair and I finally discovered the solution there is a way to set the plugin to ignore the title, aptly named: ignoreTitle: true. I'll follow up on this once I am allowed to post a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this error and came across the `ignoreTitle` option:

```
//setup input validation
validator = form.validate({
    ignoreTitle: true,
    rules: {
        city: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        city: {
            lettersonly: "you must give a valid city"
        }
    }
});
```